# How to list and print count by grouping values via loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have results like below and want them to list by grouping based on field_topic_tid and also want to display total against each field_topic_tid plus list all the elements having same tid  :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 229774
            [created] => 1515840892
            [title] => Statliga Sveaskog tillbakavisar arkeologers oro Ã¶ver avverkning och tallplantering i jÃ¤rnÃ¥lderns odlingsmarker i BÃ¶da ekopark pÃ¥ Ã–land, uppger sig varken hittat interna rapporter om skador pÃ¥ fornlÃ¤mningar eller synpunkter frÃ¥n myndigheter
            [language] => sv
            [field_topic_tid] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 229775
            [created] => 1515841997
            [title] => Indonesiens centralbank varnar fÃ¶r att kryptovalutor riskerar sÃ¥vÃ¤l allmÃ¤nhetens som finanssystemets vÃ¤lmÃ¥ende, fÃ¶rklarar sÃ¥dana investeringar riskfyllda dÃ¥ valutan inte backas av fysiska tillgÃ¥ngar samt saknar myndighetsansvar
            [language] => sv
            [field_topic_tid] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 229776
            [created] => 1515842530
            [title] => Chiles president Bachelet ber befolkningen vÃ¤lkomna och respektera pÃ¥ve Franciskus sedan tre katolska kyrkor brandbombats och pÃ¥ven hotats infÃ¶r fÃ¶rsta pÃ¥vebesÃ¶ket i landet sedan 1987, attackerna obetydliga och endast smÃ¤rre skador pÃ¥ byggnaderna enligt myndigheter
            [language] => sv
            [field_topic_tid] => 10860
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 229777
            [created] => 1515843242
            [title] => Tiotals personer frÃ¥n Nordiska motstÃ¥ndsrÃ¶relsen delar ut flygblad i GÃ¶teborg, polisen pÃ¥ plats dÃ¥ utvecklade fanor innebÃ¤r allmÃ¤n sammankomst, lugnt pÃ¥ samtliga platser men polishelikopter pÃ¥ plats fÃ¶r att fÃ¥ Ã¶versiktsbilder och Ã¶vervaka eventuella ytterligare tillstÃ¤llningar, anmÃ¤lan om brott mot ordningslagen upprÃ¤ttad
            [language] => sv
            [field_topic_tid] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 229778
            [created] => 1515843973
            [title] => TjÃ¤nstemÃ¤n tenderar tolka data i linje med sina politiska vÃ¤rderingar, enligt experimentstudie pÃ¥ Ã¶ver 2 700 anstÃ¤llda pÃ¥ VÃ¤rldsbanken och brittisk bistÃ¥ndsmyndighet
            [language] => sv
            [field_topic_tid] => 6
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 229779
            [created] => 1515844445
            [title] => Flertal sydafrikanska H&M-butiker stormade och vandaliserade i protest mot annons med svart pojke i "coolest monkey in the jungle"-trÃ¶ja
            [language] => sv
            [field_topic_tid] => 10862
        )
```

Final Results required:

```
---------------------Europa (12)--------------------- // Europa is fetched using field_topic_tid
1515858065
1515876116
1515879824
1515879962
1515884386
1515946227
1515952420
1515966754
1516003619
1516007065
1516009339
1516109628
---------------------World (11)--------------------- // World is fetched using field_topic_tid
1515840892
1515843242
1515879880
1515923083
1515963824
1516003867
1516008238
1516008877
1516097354
1516109578
1516109605
---------------------Politik (9)--------------------- // Politik is fetched using field_topic_tid
1515881114
1515881981
1515882293
1515887667
```

I am able to achieve above by using below code but I have to apply 3 foreachloops to do that, please suggest if there is alternative way.

```
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($results);

    $grouped = array();
    foreach($results as $res){
      $grouped[$res->field_topic_tid][] = (array) $res;
    }

    arsort($grouped);

    foreach($grouped as $key=>$val){

     $term = taxonomy_term_load($key);
  $section_title = taxonomy_term_title($term);
  echo "---------------------".$section_title." (".count($val).")---------------------</br>";
      foreach($val as $value){
        echo $value['created']."</br>";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all with a single loop using a second array for count

```
$grouped = array();
$counter = array();
foreach($results as $res){
  $grouped[$res->field_topic_tid][] =  $res->created;
  $counter[$res->field_topic_tid] = (isset($counter[$res->field_topic_tid]) ? $counter[$res->field_topic_tid]+1 : 1;

}
```

In grouped  you should get the valur for created  and in counter the related  values for count

Comment: Thanks but count remains one like this Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1515840892
            [1] => 1515843242
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1515841997
        )

    [10860] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1515842530
        )

)
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [10860] => 1
)

Comment: please show me the content of $res->field_topic_tid ( a sample )   looking to your data should be eg: 'world'  or Europa ..

Comment: sorry for confusion update results sample in question, its ID and I am fetching its name by function. Also I need to list title, language in next line to created. + 1 thank you for helping.

Comment: Europa and World are fetched by using function which use field_topic_tid which is actually coming in results data

Comment: Ok  .. answer  updated .. with a check on setted  value  ..but   the counter should not contain the created value  .. in my coden i don't assign this value to counter  and overall i don't append the values in counter array .. check better

Comment: Thanks for explaining .

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it by one loop by using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$grouped = array();
foreach($results as $res){
    $grouped[$res->field_topic_tid][] = $res->created; // Directly push value of created
}

arsort($grouped);

foreach($grouped as $key => $val){
    echo "---------------------".$key." (".count($val).")---------------------</br>";
    echo implode('<br>', $val); // Implode with <br> delimiter
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to list all rows one by one. For example: $value['created'] then $value['title'] and $value['language']